# How to obtain the time server takes to process a post request with curl?

Tags: web-services, curl, networking, time, libcurl

I am running a post curl request where I post a string to my webservice. Following the man page for [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) and [this](https://blog.josephscott.org/2011/10/14/timing-details-with-curl/) blog , I managed to get the following output from my curl request:

```
   time_namelookup:  0.005177
      time_connect:  0.013959
   time_appconnect:  0.000000
  time_pretransfer:  0.014062
     time_redirect:  0.000000
time_starttransfer:  1.017193
                   ----------
        time_total:  26.608273
```

I'm having trouble interpreting the results and have some questions:

1. How much time did my web service actually take to process the request?
2. What does the transfer time actually mean? What am I transferring? Is it the post payload (which is the string I'm posting?)
3. There is a huge gap between the 'time_starttransfer' event and the 'time_total'. What exactly is happening between these steps?

The [man](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) page is incredibly mysterious and not helping at all. I have also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638026/calculating-server-processing-time-with-curl) stackoverflow answer and found it to be equally confusing.
Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. total time is much greater than start transfer time leading to much higher latency.