# Azure function response is slow

Tags: azure, azure-functions

My Azure function response is very slow sometimes when called by parallel curl commands.

my function version is 1, Http trigger. Host.json is empty, so http setting is default.

When I run 50 parallel curl command with time_starttransfer parameter, I see some around 20 seconds.

But in Application insights log, maximum api duration is not so high, 13 seconds.

It looks like api duration does not match curl time_starttransfer.

Why is time_starttransfer much larger than api duration time sometimes?

In my extreme case, api duration is just a few seconds but curl response takes more 50 seconds.

I really don't understand that api execution completes very fast, 
but why curl response comes so slowly.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You need to post some code, what is your function doing? Are you calling any external services? Any other dependency that could take a while to respond (e.g image processing)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just incorrectly calculate the processing time - you need to subtract *time_connect* from *time_starttransfer*:

```sh
curl .. -w "time_connect=%{time_connect},time_starttransfer=%{time_starttransfer}\n" https://..
```

```cs
processingTime = time_starttransfer - time_connect
```

(see for details [Calculating Server Processing Time With Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17638026/303298))